# Gradle spring boot 2 spring-boot-dependencies cannot download dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I am using eclipse 2018, gradle 5.2.1, buildship 3.0.1.

My config looks like:

[image]

I try to create spring boot 2 according to [building-spring-boot-2-projects-with-gradle](https://guides.gradle.org/building-spring-boot-2-projects-with-gradle/)

The `build.gradle` is:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'com.gradle.build-scan' version '2.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
    jCenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.3.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    components {
        withModule('org.springframework:spring-beans') {
            allVariants {
                withDependencyConstraints {
                    // Need to patch constraints because snakeyaml is an optional dependency
                    it.findAll { it.name == 'snakeyaml' }.each { it.version { strictly '1.23' } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

buildScan {

    // always accept the terms of service
    termsOfServiceUrl = 'https://gradle.com/terms-of-service'
    termsOfServiceAgree = 'yes'

    // always publish a build scan
    publishAlways()
}

bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'gt4.App'
}
```

However, after I save `build.gradle`, the **Project and External Dependencies** disappear, and the spring boot jars are not downloaded too.

[image]

**What I was wrong?**

If I create spring boot project with gradle by `Spring Tool Suite 4`, the generated `build.gradle` is:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

then it works.

Do I use `spring-boot-dependencies` wrong?

Comment: I think the documentation is not correct, and there is one issue already raised on the related Github project, see : https://github.com/gradle-guides/building-spring-boot-2-projects-with-gradle/issues .

Comment: The correct way is as generated by Spring Tool Suite:  you need to apply the spring dependencies plugin with `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`, and you should not have `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.3.RELEASE'` in `dependencies` block

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Thanks. I guessed the official doc is not correct. Now you confirmed it. Strangely, the official guide is not right and it is not updated until now.

Answer (score 0):

try to deleting the local Repository and build project again to download dependancy.

Delete .m2 or .gradle folder and then Rebuild your project.

a)On a Windows machine, the .gradle or .m2 path will be:

`c:\Users\username\.m2`  or `c:\Users\username\.m2`

b)On linux machine, the .gradle or .m2 path will be:

```
USER_HOME/.m2/
```